# How can I fix "No solution" error in Cplex

Tags: python, algorithm, model, cplex, inventory

I have a model about multi product, multi-echelon supply chain network
The networks comprise number of: 1. manufacturing sites at fixed locations, 2.warehouses and distribution centers of unknown locations (to be selected from a set of potential locations), 3.customer zones at fixed locations.
It is a mixed-integer linear programming optimization problem.
The decisions to be determined include the number, location, and capacity of warehouses and distribution centers to be set up, the transportation links that need to be established in the network, and the flows and production rates of materials.
The objective is the minimization of total cost.
The model still run but it only show the data that I plug in, and no solution
This is the link to my data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-hHGvR0j2y6ojsBQMxCFh1pkeR7OgjIi?usp=sharing
This is my .mod

```
 int bigM=100000000;
 range M=1..6; // number of warehouse
 range K=1..15; // number of DC
 range KSS=1..3;
 range notKSS=4..15;
 range L=1..18; // number of customer zone
 range J=1..3; // number of plant
 range I=1..14; // number different type of product
 range E=1..6; // number of resources
 range R=1..4; //
 range place=1..3; // 1 UK, 2 ES, 3 IT
 int m;
 int k;
 int l;
 int j;
 int i;
 int e;
 int r;
  //table 3
 float p_ije0[1..6, 1..3*14] = ...;
 float p_ije[i in I, j in J, e in E] = p_ije0[e,i+14*(j-1)];
 float r_je[J][E]=...;
 float p_max[I][J]=...; // max capacity production of product i by plant j (table 2)
 float cp[J][I]=...; //unit production cost (table 4)
 float c_wm[M]=...; //establish cost of warehouse at position m (table 5)
 float c_dk[K]=...; //establish cost of DC at position k (table 5)
 float c_wh[I][M]=...;//handling cost wh m handle product i (table 5)
 float c_dh[I][K]=...;//handling cost dc k handle product i (table 5) 
 //table 7
 float c_ijm0[1..3,1..14*6]=...;
 float c_ijm[i in 1..14,j in 1..3,m in 1..6]=c_ijm0[j,i+6*(m-1)];// 
 //table 8
 float c_imk0[1..6,1..14*15]=...; 
 float c_imk[i in 1..14,m in 1..6,k in 1..15]=c_imk0[m,i+14*(k-1)];//unit transportation cost from wh m to dc k of product family f (table 8)
 //table 9
 float c_ikl0[1..15,1..14*18]=...;
 float c_ikl[i in 1..14,k in 1..15, l in 1..18]=c_ikl0[k,i+14*(l-1)]; //unit transportation cost from dc k to customer zone l of product family f (table 9)
 
 float c_r[R]=...; //transportation cost relative to the flow range (table 10)
 float d_li[I][L]=...;// product demand of product i in zone l(table 11)
 int w_max=14000; // max wh capa
 int w_min=10; //
 float ca_j[place]=...; // production capacity of plant j (table 12)
 float c_j[place]=...;// manufaturing cost of plant j (table 12)
 //table 13
 float c_w[place]=...;// infrastructure cost of wh m 
 float c_wt[place]=...;//warehouse throughput 
 float c_hw[place]=...; // wh handling cost 
 //table 14
 float c_d[place]=...;// infrastructure cost of dc k 
 float c_dt[place]=...;// dc throughput 
 float c_hd[place]=...; // dc handling cost 
 //table 14
 int d_max=7000;//max dc capa
 int d_min=10;
 int a=1;
 int b=1;
 int q_bound[R]=...;
 int q_lower[R]=...;
 float cost_upper[R]=...;
 float cost_lower[R]=...;
 dvar boolean y1[M]; // 1 if warehouse at position m is established, otherwise 0
 dvar boolean y2[K]; // 1 if dc at position k is establish, otherwise 0
 dvar boolean x1[M][K]; // 1 if warehouse m supply DC k
 dvar boolean x2[K][L]; // 1 if DC k supply customer zone l 
 dvar float w[M]; // capacity of warehouse m
 dvar float d[K]; // capacity of DC k
 dvar float p[I][J]; // production rate of product i by plant j
 dvar float q1[I][J][M]; // rate of flow of product i from plant j to warehouse m
 dvar float q2[I][M][K]; // rate of flow of product i from warehouse m to DC k
 dvar float q3[I][K][L]; // rate of flow of product i from DC k to customer zone l
 dvar boolean z1[I][J][M][R];
 dvar boolean z2[I][M][K][R];
 dvar boolean z3[I][K][L][R];
 dvar float Q_1[I][J][M][R];
 dvar float Q_2[I][M][K][R];
 dvar float Q_3[I][K][L][R];


 
 
 minimize (sum(m in M) c_wm[m]*y1[m] + sum(k in K) c_dk[k]*y2[k] +sum(i in I, j in J) cp[j][i]*p[i][j] + sum(i in I, m in M) c_wh[i][m]*(sum(j in J)q1[i][j][m])+sum(i in I, k in K)c_dh[i][k]*(sum( m in M)q2[i][m][k]))+ sum( i in I, j in J, m in M)c_ijm[i][j][m]+sum(i in I, m in M, k in K)c_imk[i][m][k]+sum(i in I, k in K, l in L)c_ikl[i][k][l]);

 subject to {
   forall(m in M, k in K)
     x1[m][k] <= y1[m]; // (1)
   forall (k in KSS)
    sum(m in M) x1[m][k]==y2[k]; //(2)
   forall (m in M,k in notKSS)
     x1[m][k]<=y2[k];  //(3)
   forall (k in K,l in L)
     x2[k][l]<=y2[k]; //(4)
   forall(l in L)
     sum(k in K) x2[k][l]==1; //(5)
   forall (i in I, j in J, m in M)
     q1[i][j][m] <= 40*y1[m]; //(6)
   forall (i in I, m in M, k in K)
     q2[i][m][k] <= 40*x1[m][k]; //(7)
   forall (i in I, l in L, k in K)
     q3[i][k][l] <= 40*x2[k][l]; //(8)
   forall ( m in M, k in K)
     sum(i in I)q2[i][m][k]>=2*x1[m][k]; //(9)
   forall ( k in K, l in L)
     sum(i in I)q3[i][k][l]>=2*x2[k][l];  //(10)
   forall( i in I,j in J)
   p[i][j]==sum(m in M) q1[i][j][m]; //(11)
   forall(i in I, m in M)
     sum(j in J) q1[i][j][m]== sum(k in K) q2[i][m][k]; //(12)
   forall(i in I, k in K)
     sum(m in M) q2[i][m][k]==sum(l in L) q3[i][k][l]; //(13)
   forall(i in I, l in L)
     sum(k in K) q3[i][k][l]== d_li[i][l];  //(14)
   forall(i in I, j in J)
     5<=p[i][j] && p[i][j]<=p_max[i][j]; //(15)
   forall(j in J, e in E)
    sum(i in I)p_ije[i][j][e]*p[i][j]<= r_je[j][e] ; //(16)
   forall(m in M)
      w[m]<=w_max*y1[m] &&  w[m]>=w_min*y1[m] ;  //(17)  
   forall (k in K)  //18
      d[k]<=d_max*y2[k] && d[k]>=d_min*y2[k];
   forall(m in M)
     w[m]>=sum(i in I, k in K)a*q2[i][m][k]; //(19)
   forall (k in K)
     d[k]>=sum(i in I, l in L)b*q3[i][k][l]; //(20)
   forall(i in I, j in J) //(21)
     p[i][j]>=0;  
   forall(i in I, j in J, m in M) //(22)
     q1[i][j][m]>=0;
   forall(i in I, m in M,k in K)
     q2[i][m][k]>=0; //(23)
   forall(i in I, k in K, l in L)
     q3[i][k][l]>=0; //(24)    
   forall(i in I, j in J, m in M)
   sum(r in R) z1[i][j][m][r]==1; //(29)
   forall(i in I, j in J, m in M, r in R)
     q_bound[r]*z1[i][j][m][r]>=Q_1[i][j][m][r] && q_lower[r]*z1[i][j][m][r]<=Q_1[i][j][m][r]; //(30)
   forall(i in I, j in J, m in M)
     sum(i in I)q1[i][j][m]== sum(r in R)q_bound[r]; //(31)
   forall(i in I, j in J, m in M) //(32)
     c_ijm[i][j][m]==sum(r in R) (cost_lower[r]*z1[i][j][m][r]+(q_bound[r]-q_lower[r]*z1[i][j][m][r])*(cost_upper[r]-cost_lower[r])/(q_bound[r]-q_lower[r]));
   forall(i in I, m in M, k in K) //(33)
     sum(r in R)z2[i][m][k][r]==1;     
   forall(i in I, m in M, k in K, r in R) //(34)
       q_bound[r]*z2[i][m][k][r]>=Q_2[i][m][k][r] && q_lower[r]*z2[i][m][k][r]<=Q_2[i][m][k][r];  
   forall(i in I, m in M, k in K) //(35)
     sum(i in I)q2[i][m][k]==sum(r in R)q_bound[r];  
   forall(i in 1..3, m in 1..6, k in 1..15) //(36)
     c_imk[m][i][k]==sum(r in R) (cost_lower[r]*z2[i][m][k][r]+(q_bound[r]-q_lower[r]*z2[i][m][k][r])*(cost_upper[r]-cost_lower[r])/(q_bound[r]-q_lower[r]));  
   forall(i in I, k in K, l in L) //(37)
     sum(r in R)z3[i][k][l][r]==1; 
   forall(i in I, k in K, l in L, r in R) //(38)
       q_bound[r]*z3[i][k][l][r]>=Q_3[i][k][l][r] && q_lower[r]*z3[i][k][l][r]<=Q_3[i][k][l][r]; 
   forall(i in I, k in K, l in L) //(39)
     sum(i in I)q3[i][k][l]==sum(r in R)q_bound[r];
   forall(i in I, k in K, l in L) //(40)
     c_ikl[i][k][l]==sum(r in R) (cost_lower[r]*z3[i][k][l][r]+(q_bound[r]-q_lower[r]*z3[i][k][l][r])*(cost_upper[r]-cost_lower[r])/(q_bound[r]-q_lower[r]));
}
```

This is my .dat file:

```
SheetConnection Edata("data.xlsx");
p_max from SheetRead(Edata ,"p_max");
cp    from SheetRead(Edata ,"cp");
c_wm  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_wm");
c_dk  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_dk");
c_wh  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_wh1");
c_dh  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_dh");
c_r   from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_r");
d_li  from SheetRead(Edata ,"d_li");
ca_j  from SheetRead(Edata ,"ca_j");
c_j   from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_j");
c_w   from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_w");
c_wt  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_wt");
c_hw  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_hw");
c_d   from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_d");
c_dt  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_dt");
c_hd  from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_hd");
p_ije0 from SheetRead(Edata ,"p_ije0");
c_ijm0 from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_ijm");
c_imk0 from SheetRead(Edata ,"c_imk");
c_ikl0 from SheetRead(Edata,"c_ikl");
r_je from SheetRead(Edata ,"r_ej");

q_bound from SheetRead(Edata,"q_bound");
q_lower from SheetRead(Edata,"q_lower");
cost_upper from SheetRead(Edata,"cost_upper");
cost_lower from SheetRead(Edata,"cost_lower");
```

Comment: You should also share .dat so that other users can try by themselves

Answer (score 0):

If you name your constraints like in [Conflict and Relaxation](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooconflictandrelaxation.mod)  from [Making Decision Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) you will be able to understand better what the issues are.

With your model for instance, if we keep only

```
//minimize (sum(m in M) c_wm[m]*y1[m] + sum(k in K) c_dk[k]*y2[k] +sum(i in I, j in J) cp[j][i]*p[i][j] + sum(i in I, m in M) c_wh[i][m]*(sum(j in J)q1[i][j][m])+sum(i in I, k in K)c_dh[i][k]*(sum( m in M)q2[i][m][k]))+ sum( i in I, j in J, m in M)c_ijm[i][j][m]+sum(i in I, m in M, k in K)c_imk[i][m][k]+sum(i in I, k in K, l in L)c_ikl[i][k][l];

 subject to {


   forall(i in I, j in J)
     {
     ct15a:5<=p[i][j] ;
     ct15b:p[i][j]<=p_max[i][j]; //(15)
   }     

}
```

then we ll see in the IDE conflicts between ct15a and ct15b

```
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[1][2]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[5][1]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[5][3]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[6][3]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[8][2]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[9][2]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[10][2]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[11][1]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[12][3]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[14][2]
87  [-Infinity,0]   [-Infinity,5]   ct15b[14][3]
```